# how to wrap elments in a div if they were created using sveltes {#each} block

Tags: javascript, svelte

i am building a calender app in svelte and i want to wrap each set of 4 months into a div element so i can put a background image behind each of them.

each of the months were created using data from arrays.
and the svelte {#each block}.

```
{#each Object.entries(yearObj) as [key, value], index (key)}
    {#if index > 7}
<div class="inline-block bg-slate-900 flex flex-col flex-nowrap items-center p-0 border break-after-page">  
    <p class="block text-center py-1.5 ">{key}</p>
    <table class=" bg-slate-500 bg-opacity-50 w-full">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            {#each week_days as col}        
            {#if col == 'Sunday' || col == 'Saturday'}
                <th class="text-purple-900 border border-gray-900 shrink px-2.5 py-1.5">{col}</th>
            {:else}
                <th class="text-black border border-gray-900 shrink px-2.5 py-1.5">{col}</th>
            {/if}
            {/each}
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {#each value as mon}            
        <tr>
        {#each mon as cell}     
            <td class="border border-gray-900 py-1.5">{cell}</td>
        {/each}
        </tr>
        {/each}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

for more code context click the link
i couldnt include more code as it was too much code sorry for inconvience.

https://github.com/kalvinyuu/calender-svelte/blob/master/src/routes/%2Bpage.svelte

Comment: Please include *all* relevant code in the question itself, do not just link to it. You should construct a *minimal* example first.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you could probably just form groups and use an additional `{#each}`, e.g.

```html
<script>
    const data = Array.from({ length: 25 }).map((e, i) => i + 1);
    
    function partitionIntoGroups(array, n) {
        const groups = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += n) {
            groups.push(array.slice(i, i + n));
        }
        return groups;
    }
</script>

{#each partitionIntoGroups(data, 4) as group}
    <div class="group">
        {#each group as item}
            <span>{item}</span>
        {/each}
    </div>
{/each}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/48d848f7ba6b45c2a34579b5a51afb03?version=3.55.0)